# compare two tables on many columns using checksum?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, join, database-design

I want to compare two huge Tables, with the same columns, to find records which have different values. (many of the rows in both Tables are the same)

It takes a huge amount of time, the performance is very bad, the query now looks like this:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  table1 a
    INNER JOIN  table2 b
       ON a.value!=b.value
      OR  a.value!=b.value
      OR  a.value!=b.value
      OR  a.value!=b.value
      OR  a.value!=b.value
      OR  a.value!=b.value
      OR  a.value!=b.value OR...
    WHERE  a.id=1
      AND  b.id=2
      AND  a.specialvalue=b.specialvalue;
```

The Idea is to create a checksum of all the values I need to compare and compare just the checksum of the rows. My question is: Is this a good approach? Will there be a performance improvement? Is it even possible to compare two rows with like 100k records each in a reasonable amound of time?

Comment: Do you need to do this often or just once? Can you share the schema of the tables?

also... is the `WHERE` clause the real one?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check each of 100K rows against each other of the 100K, that is about 50 *billion* comparisons.  It will take longer than you like.  However you could do this:

```
CREATE Cksums (
    md5 CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii,
    id ...,   -- PK of the row
    INDEX(md5)
);

INSERT INTO Cksums (md5, id)
    SELECT
           MD5(CONCAT_WS("\t", col2, col3, ...),
           id
        FROM your_table;
```

Then look for dup rows:

```
SELECT md5,
       GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS dup_ids
    FROM Cksums
    GROUP BY md5
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

DROP TABLE Cksums;  -- cleanup
```

That will effectively do the 50 billion comparisons via two 100K table scans (one to build Cksums, one to check it).

Caveats:

- I don't know whether this handles `NULLs` nicely.
- I assume that "tab" is not used in any of the columns.
- `BLOBs` should be pulled out via `HEX(the_blob)` to avoid various issues in the `CONCAT_WS`.
- If too many rows are identical (hundreds), the `GROUP_CONCAT` will truncate the list.
- I claim (some people disagree) that a 128-bit MD5 is sufficient.  If you have 9 trillion md5s, there is only one chance in 9 trillion that two will be wrongly the same.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to check if the two tables are identical is to use MySQL's [`CHECKSUM TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/checksum-table.html) command. If the two tables give the same checksum, then all data in the two tables is perfectly in sync, and you're done.

If the checksum differs, then you can check in more detail to find out which rows are different.

[Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-toolkit) includes a tool [`pt-table-sync`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-sync.html) that performs the data comparison between two tables more efficiently. You need Perl installed, and the Perl modules DBI and DBD::mysql.

For example, I want to compare two identical tables in my test database, the tables are called deadlocks and deadlocks2. First I just want to see what the differences are:

```
$ pt-table-sync --print h=localhost,D=test,t=deadlocks t=deadlocks2
```

The output shows a series of `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements that would be required to make the deadlocks2 table have identical data as the deadlocks table.

If you're ready to sync them, change print to execute, and it will perform the SQL changes:

```
$ pt-table-sync --execute h=localhost,D=test,t=deadlocks t=deadlocks2
```

After that, the `CHECKSUM TABLE` for each table should match.

Another option is [mysqldbcompare](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqldbcompare.html) from the MySQL Utilities. I don't have as much experience with this tool, but it appears it will compare data in all the tables of two complete databases. I don't know if there's an option to compare two tables with different names but similar structure.

Percona Toolkit and MySQL Utilities are both free software.

Answer (score 1):

There are some great answers here including `pt-table-checksum` a favourite of mine.

If you only need to do this once and want a quick way of finding the differences consider using `mysqldump` or `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` to dump out the tables into two separate files and then use the good old `diff` command on the command line.